# Estimating the volume of a beerglass

Tags: geometry, volume

Most who have been to college recognizes the red glasses used for beerpong and alcohol consumption. *My question is about why one method is better at estimating the volume and why*.

[image]

The exact volume of a frostum with a small radius $r$, larger radius $R$ and $h$ is given as

$$
    V = \frac{\pi}{3} ( R^2 + rR + r^2 ) h 
$$

One method to estimate the volume of the frustum is to take the average volume of a cylinder with radius $R$ and $r$. Eg

$$
       V_1 
    = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \pi R^2 h + \pi r^2 h \right]
    = \frac{\pi}{2} \left( R^2 + r^2 \right) h
$$

Another method is to estimate the volume by taking the averages of the radii. So $\tau = (R + r)/2$.

$$
      V_2 
    = \pi \tau^2 h 
    = \pi \left( \frac{R+r}{2} \right)^2h 
    = \frac{\pi}{4} \left( R^2 + 2rR + r^2 \right) h
$$

By comparison one now obtains

$$
  V - V_1 = -\frac{\pi}{6}(R-r)^2h
  \quad \text{and} \quad
  V - V_2 =  \frac{\pi}{12}(R-r)^2h
$$

Now I have two questions.

**1: Why is $V_2$ a better estimate of the volume of the frustum, and why is $V_1 > V > V_2$?**

**2: Why is $V_2$** *exactly* **twice as good as V_1?** Eg $|V - V_1| = 2|V - V_2|$